# Problems with changing a function variable inside another lower function in R?

Tags: r, environment-variables

I need to open files (matrices) from a directory and apply a function **pca** on each one. It uses another function **count_pc** which is thought to null diagonals in the matrix step by step and add recalculated PC1 to a the table *pcs* from the previous function. At the start, I didn't think of environments so **count_pca** was crashing with the error "unknown variable". Then I tried to do it this way:

```
files <- list.files()

count_pc <- function(x, env = parent.frame()) {
  diag(file[x:nrow(file),]) <- 0
  diag(file[,x:nrow(file)]) <- 0
  pcn <- prcomp(file, scale = FALSE)
  pcn <- data.frame(pcn$rotation)
  pcs <- cbind(pcs, pcn$PC1)
}

pca <- function(filename) {
  file <- as.matrix(read.table(filename))
  pc <- prcomp(file, scale = FALSE)
  pc <- data.frame(pc$rotation)
  pc1 <- pc$PC1
  pcs <- data.frame(pc1)
  for (k in 1:40) {
    count_pc(k)
  }
  new_filename <- strsplit(filename, "_")[[1]][3]
  print(pcs)
  colnames(pcs) <- paste0(0:40, rep("_bins_deleted", 40))
  write.table(pcs, file=paste(new_filename, "eigenvectors", sep="_"))
  return(apply(pcs, 2, cor, y = pc1))
}

ldply(files, pca)
```

And indeed, **count_pc** does not crash with above error but, unfortunately, it crashes with the new one:

```
"colnames<-`(`*tmp*`, value = c("0_bins_deleted", "1_bins_deleted",  :
'names' [41] attribute must be the same length as the vector [1]"
```

which means that **count_pc** does not change needed variables. First, I thought the problem might be connected with using `sapply(1:40, count_pc)` so I replaced it with a cycle. But it didn't help. I've also tried to use `environment(count_pc) <- environment()` in the **pca** but it didn't help either (as well as changing variable names in **count_pc** to env$'name'). I don't know what to do and googling doesn't seem to help.

Comment: Pass every object needed inside a function as a parameter. Make sure that your functions return everything needed outside them. You are trying to create functions with side effects which is bad practice.

Comment: Thank you, I've changed the code and it works now.